# Can we create threads in classic ASP?

Tags: multithreading, iis, asp-classic, iis-6

My simple question is
Can we create threads in classic ASP?
If yes then HOW ?

Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not native methods in VBScript that allow you to spawn new threads. On the other hand you could call COM components written in some other language such as C++ which are multithreaded.