# Multi threading in Classic ASP

Tags: multithreading, asp-classic

I would like to know how to set Multithreading in classic asp, and I am using iis7.5.

I am stuck with this. Can anyone please provide some help, and that will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean? you want to create threads within ASP script? i don't think it's possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we create threads in classic ASP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538065/can-we-create-threads-in-classic-asp)

Comment: could you hack something by using Javascript instead of VBScript and `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1):

ASP pooling is single thread ... you would need to use a programming language where it can be use, normally .NET.